# Set variable value in function and access in other function

Tags: php

I want to assign some values to a variable in some functions and then get that variable value in another function. 
How I can do that? I am trying this, but it does not work.

```
<?php

global $var;
function test1(){
    $var .= "value1 ";
}

function test2(){
    $var .= "value2 ";
}

function test3(){
    echo $var;
}

test3();
```

Comment: I suggest you NOT to do this, but you are inverting. You should use global INSIDE the functions, not in the outer scope...

Comment: See the manual on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works this way..

The **`global`** keyword has to be used inside the function on your context. As your functions `test1()`, `test2()` & `test()` cannot access the value of `$var` (which has `something`) since it is out of their scope. Thus we introduce **`global`** inside of the function to make it accessible.

```
<?php

$var = "something";

function test1(){
    global $var; // You need to call global here (inside the function)
    $var .= "value1 ";
}

function test2(){
    global $var;
    $var .= "value2 ";
}

function test3(){
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}

test3();
```

Comment: Quite surprizing to see +1 instead of -10 on this answer

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Hmm lol now it is no more. It will be better if you point out what went wrong above. Criticizing without a reason is useless. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

U can do this too.

```
<?php

function test1(){
    return "value1 ";
}

function test2(){
    return "value2 ";
}

function test3($var){
    $var .= test1();
    $var .= test2();
    echo $var;
}

test3($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way

```
$var = value;
function test1($var){
    return "value1 ". $var;
}

function test2($var){
    return "value2 ". $var;
}

function test3($var){
    echo $var;
}

$var = value;
$var = test1($var);
$var = test2($var);
test3($var);
```

Comment: We know this is right way. But you need to explain what you are doing in the code.. That is to educate the OP that you are passing parameters to a function and not using `global` keyword as such. Posting a plain code does not help the OP as well as anyone.

Answer (score -2):

Also you can use $_SESSION variables like this :

```
$_SESSION['var1']="someting";
```

And use this in every page or function you want.

Comment: "need" - no. "can use" - yes.

Comment: @frnhr We shouldn't encourage bad practices... Sessions are used for store data BETWEEN requests, here he just wants to use it in the same request...